# Convert Time DataType into AM PM Format:

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, time

I have one Table which has two fields such as "StartTime" and "EndTime". The DataType of the Two columns are Time.

So the Values of the Table looks like as follows:

```
TableA:

            StartTime                EndTime
       ------------------         ----------------
        17:30:00.0000000          17:57:00.0000000
```

But I need the result as

```
            StartTime                EndTime
       ------------------         ----------------
            05:30 PM                 05:57 PM
```

When I select the table. How to get time in AM PM Format?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use following syntax to convert a time to AM PM format.

Replace the field name with the value in following query.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('17:30:00.0000000' AS TIME),100)
```

Output: 5:30PM

Better option is available with Sql 2012. First parameter should be of datetime data type.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011 13:14';
SELECT FORMAT(@d,'hh:mm tt')
```

Output : 01:14 PM

Comment: How can we add the space between minute and AM/PM?

Comment: There must be a better way but I did this:
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(26),CAST('17:30:00.0000000' AS TIME),109),':00.0000000',' ')
Since for my purposes, I do not use the milliseconds, but I added them to replace them with ' '

Comment: @JonH I am also looking for a direct method. Please inform me if you find one.

Comment: This does not include a space between the AM and PM like the user requested.

Comment: It's not pretty, but here's one way you can add the space:
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST('17:30:00.0000000' AS TIME), 100), 'P', ' P'), 'A', ' A')

Comment: @hurleystylee, they may be many other indirect ways to put space before AM/PM and your solution is from one of them. Thanks for putting this.

Comment: @RomilKumarJain: sir, can you please advise if the value is in `smallint` like `17` and we need result in time format like `5:00 PM` then what change we can make in your script?

Comment: @RahulHendawe The mentioned script already give 5 for value passed 17. May you share the actual input and expected output?

Comment: @RomilKumarJain: No sir it will throw an error: `Explicit conversion from data type smallint to time is not allowed.` for `smallint` data type.

Comment: `declare @a smallint =17;
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(@a AS TIME),100)`

Comment: @RahulHendawe Try declare @a smallint =17; select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(cast (@a as varchar(2)) + ':0:0' AS TIME),100)

Comment: @RomilKumarJain: tysm sir, it is working perfectly except for 24 when i put 24 in `@a` it should return 11:59 pm but it is throwing an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`  +1 from me :)

Comment: @RahulHendawe 24:00:00 is not a valid time, so it's giving error. It should be 00:00:00  :)

Comment: Yes sir, I applied a case as per requirements :)

Answer (score 107):

In SQL 2012 you can use the Format() function.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Skip casting if the column type is (datetime).

**Example:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(StartTime,'hh:mm tt') AS StartTime
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 17):

Here are the various ways you may pull this (depending on your needs).

Using the **Time** DataType:

```
DECLARE @Time Time = '15:04:46.217'
SELECT --'3:04PM'
       CONVERT(VarChar(7), @Time, 0),

       --' 3:04PM' --Leading Space.
       RIGHT(' ' + CONVERT(VarChar(7), @Time, 0), 7),

       --' 3:04 PM' --Space before AM/PM.
       STUFF(RIGHT(' ' + CONVERT(VarChar(7), @Time, 0), 7), 6, 0, ' '),

       --'03:04 PM' --Leading Zero.  This answers the question above.
       STUFF(RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VarChar(7), @Time, 0), 7), 6, 0, ' ')

       --'03:04 PM' --This only works in SQL Server 2012 and above.  :)
       ,FORMAT(CAST(@Time as DateTime), 'hh:mm tt')--Comment out for SS08 or less.
```

Using the **DateTime** DataType:

```
DECLARE @Date DateTime = '2016-03-17 15:04:46.217'
SELECT --' 3:04PM' --No space before AM/PM.
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar(19), @Date, 0), 7),

       --' 3:04 PM' --Space before AM/PM.
       STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar(19), @Date, 0), 7), 6, 0, ' '),

       --'3:04 PM' --No Leading Space.
       LTRIM(STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar(19), @Date, 0), 7), 6, 0, ' ')),

       --'03:04 PM' --Leading Zero.
       STUFF(REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VarChar(19), @Date, 0), 7), ' ', '0'), 6, 0, ' ')

       --'03:04 PM' --This only works in SQL Server 2012 and above.  :)
       ,FORMAT(@Date, 'hh:mm tt')--Comment line out for SS08 or less.
```

Comment: What if I only want PM or AM to be displayed?

Comment: `STUFF` is much better than `Format`

Comment: @abdulqayyum Agreed.  I've taken huge performance hits before with `FORMAT()`, so now I avoid it altogether.  It's convenience, but at too steep a cost.  You never know how these things may affect a query in the future.  It may run fine on a small set now, but years later it'll be choking on a few thousand of records.  Source: [Format is nice and all, but...](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) and [Beware the Performance Impact of the T-SQL Format Function](https://informaticsilluminated.com/beware-the-performance-impact-of-the-t-sql-format-function/)

Answer (score 8):

This returns like **11:30 AM**

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), FromTime, 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FromTime, 9),2)
from tablename
```

Comment: This works okay; however you also get results like 14:00 PM

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 100) AS ST,
       CONVERT(varchar, EndTime, 100) AS ET
FROM some_table
```

or

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 100),8)),8) AS ST,
       RIGHT('0'+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, EndTime, 100),8)),8) AS ET
FROM some_table
```

Comment: Cleanest solution.

Comment: this adds an extra 0 when hour has 2 digits (10-12) `010:40AM`

Answer (score 3):

```
> SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 100) as date_n_time
> SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),convert(time,GETDATE()),100) as req_time
> select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)+' '+convert(varchar(20),convert(time,getdate()),100)

> Result (1):- Jun  9 2018 11:36AM
> result(2):-  11:35AM
> Result (3):-  06/10/2018 11:22AM
```

Answer (score 3):

> select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('17:30:00.0000000' AS TIME),100)

almost works perfectly except for the space issue.
if that were changed to:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('17:30:00.0000000' AS TIME),22)
```

...then you get the space. And additionally, if the column being converted is already of `TIME` format, you can skip the cast if you reference it directly.

**Final answer**:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),StartTime,22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple functions, but this will give you what you need (tested on SQL Server 2008)

**Edit:** The following works not only for a `time` type, but for a `datetime` as well.

`SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20),StartTime,22), 10, 11) AS Start, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20),EndTime,22), 10, 11) AS End FROM [TableA];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ' 4:07PM', 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), ' 4:07PM', 9),2) as ConvertedTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @temp varchar(50)
set @temp = convert(varchar(max),STUFF(STUFF('645P',2,0,':'),5,0,' '))
select @temp

SELECT CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(@temp,1)='P' THEN REPLACE(@temp,'p','PM')
        WHEN RIGHT(@temp,1)='A' THEN REPLACE(@temp,'a','AM')
        END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('2014-05-28 16:07:54.647' AS TIME),100) as CreatedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select right(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),100),7)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using @Saikh's answer above, the 2nd option, you can add a space between the time itself and the AM or PM.

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(TIME,myDateTime),100)),2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(TIME,myDateTime),100)),3,20)) AS [Time],
```

Messy I know, but it's the solution I chose. Strange that the CONVERT() doesn't add that space automatically. *SQL Server 2008 R2*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `FORMAT()` function like this:

```
-- Returns "03:15 AM"
DECLARE @iniTme TIME = '03:15:30'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@iniTme AS DATETIME),  'hh:mm tt')

-- Returns "03:15 PM"
DECLARE @endTme TIME = '15:15:30'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@endTme AS DATETIME),  'hh:mm tt')
```

Comment: You need to add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why the code below was not mentioned by anyone.

```
select  FORMAT(CAST(@Your_time_data_type AS datetime),'hh:mm tt') AS TimeStr
```

eg.
`select  FORMAT(CAST('12:30' AS datetime),'hh:mm tt') AS TimeIn`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),106)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()),100)
```

-> RESULT  : `30 Jan 2023 3:02PM`