# Change Time to include Hours/Minutes AND AM/PM

Tags: sql, time

Using SQL and Looking at a list provided by w3schools on Date conversion (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) it looks like there isn't really away to get Hours/Minutes AND AM/PM without getting a whole bunch of stuff in the front of the time.

I'm currently using a 24 hour time in my query

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),sa.StartDateTime,108) ApptStartTime
```

This spits out something like this

```
14:55
```

And I'm looking for something like this

```
02:55 PM
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Time DataType into AM PM Format:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828492/convert-time-datatype-into-am-pm-format)

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS TIME),100)`

Comment: Did you look at the list provided by Microsoft?

Comment: @Shiva probably because the example query uses MS-SQL's CONVERT syntax

Comment: @DanBracuk Yep - looks like it also doesn't have what I'm looking for hopefully the answer lies in one of these answers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @GoatCO - Yes!  You were correct! Had to cast is as time then put it into a convert :)

Comment: The link you found did have the answer, indirectly.  Data style 100 returns AM and PM.  Then it's a matter of string functions to strip out the date portion and add a leading zero to the hours part, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW - so this post could have a definitive answer - from @Goat CO

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS TIME),100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
/* Sample SQL */

DECLARE @d1 datetime;
SELECT @d1 = '5/30/2014 21:46:59';
SELECT Convert(varchar, Convert(time, @d1), 100) AS ApptStartTime;
/* ApptStartTime=9:46PM */

DECLARE @d2 datetime;
SELECT @d2 = '5/30/2014 01:19:11';
SELECT Convert(varchar, Convert(time, @d2), 100) AS ApptStartTime;
/* ApptStartTime=1:19AM */
```

In your case, you would use:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar, Convert(time, sa.StartDateTime), 100) AS ApptStartTime;
```

<sub>**EDIT:**</sub>

If the leading 0 and space is important, you would use:

```
SELECT Stuff(Right('0'+Convert(varchar, Convert(time, sa.StartDateTime), 100), 7), 6, 0, ' ') AS ApptStartTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that adds a leading 0 and inserts a space before the AM/PM:

```
SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),sa.StartDateTime,100),13,7),' ','0'),6,0,' ');
```

or just

```
SELECT STUFF(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),sa.StartDateTime,100),13,7),6,0,' ');
```

if you don't need the leading 0

Note that this would be easier/cleaner in the UI/Report layer if that's a possibility.

Comment: I actually don't need the additional zeros before 2 - 2:00PM would work just fine :)