# How to show the time in AM/PM format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I get the timestamphour column to show only the time like 5 AM, 6 AM etc?

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour , 0, callstartdt), 0) as TimeStampHour, Count(*) as count
FROM table_one
where month(CallStartDt)=5 and day(callstartdt) = 16
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, callstartdt), 0)
ORDER BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, callstartdt), 0);

TimeStampHour               count
2016-05-16 05:00:00.000     1
2016-05-16 06:00:00.000     4
2016-05-16 07:00:00.000     4
2016-05-16 08:00:00.000     113
2016-05-16 09:00:00.000     110
2016-05-16 10:00:00.000     131
```

I'm using sql-2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Time DataType into AM PM Format:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828492/convert-time-datatype-into-am-pm-format)

Comment: select cast(case when DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) > 12 then DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) - 12 else DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) end as varchar(2)) +' ' + 
  case when DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) > 12 then 'PM' else 'AM' end

Comment: @kostya thanks, only issue im having its with  order the time

Comment: you could add another field to select, group by, order by like DATEPART(HOUR, callstartdt) just make sure it is the first in the order by

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to show the hour with AM, PM try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour , 0, callstartdt), 0),'hh tt') AS TimeStampHour ....
```

This takes the rounded hour that you had and uses Format() to show only hour : 'hh' and AM/PM : 'tt'.  You can also show the full time with AM/PM using Format(GetDate(),100).

The DATEPART solution in the comments should also work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/7727

Comment: oops seems like 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: when you say you're using Sql-2012 you definitely mean SQL Server 2012 right?

Comment: yeah Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0, weird

Comment: it is so weird, that is SQL Server 2012 and Format is available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx s/b available for sql 2012+ (this among 10 other pages about Format)